# How to set value of combobox with two columns?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I am using an unbound form. I have a combobox called `PO_Number`, and a combobox called `Vendor_Name`. In an after update event for the PO_Number, I use the `PO_Number` and get the `Vendor_Name`. In VBA, I try to set the value of the combobox like so:

```
Vendor_Name.Value = rs!Vendor_Name
```

It runs but the text does not show up in the combobox.

How can I set the value of a combobox?

After Update event:

```
Private Sub PO_Number_AfterUpdate()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim sql As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
sql = "SELECT v.Vendor_Name, p.PO_Date, p.Description FROM PO as p INNER JOIN Vendor as v ON p.Vendor_Number = v.Vendor_Number WHERE p.PO_Number = " & PO_Number.value
    
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
        
    Vendor_Name.Value = rs!Vendor_Name
    PO_Date.value = rs!PO_Date
    Description_Tb.value = rs!Description
End If
    
Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    
    Err.Raise Number:=Err.Number, Description:=Err.Description
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I looked through several answers, all of which were for C# or VB.Net.

**EDIT:**
I considered using a textbox for Vendor Name, but I need the combobox because the user needs to select a different vendor.

I also realized there are two columns to my `Vendor_Name` combobox. The first stores the `Vendor_Number`, the second stores the `Vendor_Name`. The bound column is set to 1 (Vendor_Name).

How can I set the value of the combobox with two columns?

I would like to set it like so:

```
Vendor_Name.Column(0) = rs!Vendor_Number
Vendor_Name.Column(1) = rs!Vendor_Name
```

but it gives me:

> Run time error 424.
> Object required

Comment: Why do you need to set combobox with vendor name - why not just a textbox? Include vendor name as column of PO_Number then expression in textbox references column by index (index begins with 0): `=PO_Number.Column(1)`.

Comment: @June7 Just updated my question. I have a workaround in mind, just set a disabled textbox value to the old vendor, and have the combobox to select the new vendor but I would like to resolve this issue.

Comment: Okay, I am confused. Are you using an UNBOUND form?

Comment: @June7 I added to the beginning of my question and edit section. Hopefully that makes it more clear. Yes it is unbound. The Vendor_Name combobox has 2 fields, 1 with 0 width, and the bound column is set to the second column, the vendor name. More details in the question.

Comment: So why are you using UNBOUND form? I tested setting combobox to Vendor_Number and works. Pull Vendor_Number not Vendor_Name. Make sure combobox ColumnWidths: 0";1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source of issue is misunderstanding BoundColumn property. BoundColumn is not zero-based.

If combobox RowSource is `SELECT Vendor_Number, Vendor_Name FROM Vendors;` and BoundColumn is 1 then it is looking at Vendor_Number, not Vendor_Name.

Column Index is zero-based. So Column(0) refers to first column.

Need to set combobox Value property with Vendor_Number then with ColumnWidths set as 0";1", associated Vendor_Name will display.

Use BOUND form and BOUND controls and less VBA will be needed and a lot of these complications will go away.